# having trouble with the logic behind calculating a score for my hangman game

Tags: c++, logic

im running a basic game of hangman, the code works but im currently stuck on a logic bug involving how the score is calculated, the program is allowing the user to input the same word multiple times and still giving credit towards winning

for example: if the word that is randomly picked from my list is "apple" and the user inputs "p" they will reveal two words if they input "p" again they  will not reveal anymore letters but they will still gain two points towards the win and if they input "p" again the user will win the game

this is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int maxWrongGuesses = 10;
    int letter;
    char guess;
    string display;
    bool won = false;
    bool guessing = true;
    int correctGuesses = 0;
    int wrongGuesses = 0;

    cout << "Lets Play a Game of Hangman!!! \n";

    vector<string> word;
    string line;
    ifstream hangmanfile("hangman.txt");
    if (hangmanfile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(hangmanfile, line))
        {

            word.push_back(line);
        }
        hangmanfile.close();
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file";

    unsigned seed = time(0);

    srand(seed);
    int answer = rand() % word.size();

    string currentWord = word.at(answer);

    cout << currentWord << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < currentWord.length(); i++)
    {
        display = display + "_ ";
    }
    while (guessing)
    {
        bool correctGuess = false;
        cout << display << "\n";

        cout << "Please Enter Your Guess \n";
        cin >> guess;

        for (int i = 0; i < currentWord.length(); i++)
        {
            if (guess == currentWord[i])
            {
                display[i * 2] = guess;
                correctGuesses++;
                correctGuess = true;
            }
            if (correctGuesses == currentWord.length())
            {
                guessing = false;
                won = true;
            }
        }
        if (!correctGuess)
        {
            cout << "Wrong Try Again \n";
            wrongGuesses++;
            cout << wrongGuesses << "\n";
        }
        if (maxWrongGuesses == wrongGuesses)
        {
            guessing = false;
        }

    }
    if (won)
    {
        cout << display << "\n";
        cout << "Congratz You Won!! \n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The Answer Was " << currentWord << "\n";
        cout << "Sorry You Lose \n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the logic behind how to fix this has got me stumped lack of sleep and long days of work i guess but i need a bit of help with how to fix this problem.

Comment: You need a way to check if a letter has been guessed before before you call it a correct guess. Probably the easiest way is to check if the current guess is present in the variable "display".

Comment: keep a vector of past guesses, check it to make sure they don't re-use the same guess. No reason to search any strings.

Answer (score 0):

You will add points only if `display[index]=='_'` and the user got the letter correctly. I think you can take it from here.